# Can I intentionally make duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion

I am just wondering if I can make a question that addresses the same concerns as another question but is phrased differently. Maybe I may make a question and then immediately make a comment that I am going to flag it as a duplicate. Does the system care about the number of flags you generated yourself on yourself?

Comment: Good Question, not a Good idea.  this might be good for a FAQ.  I am not around enough to know for sure though

Answer (score 5):

Intentionally asking questions that you want to be closed as duplicates is probably not a good idea. We want this kind of thing to happen organically.

If you feel like an existing question could be worded better, you have edit privileges.

Comment: A related question would be: once you gain the privilege of closing questions as duplicates, can you intentionally make duplicates and then immediately close them?

Comment: Please don't. still takes 5 votes to close

Comment: Wow. How did you answer so fast? Anyway, once you gain the position of moderator, can you close the question then? (I feel like Abraham talking to God.)

Comment: @Anonymous inbox notifications are updated via websockets, so it's live if you're paying attention to your browser. No, no need to close the question, it' a good one and can stay open

Comment: @Anonymous I think wax missed the point of your last question, but the answer is STILL DON'T. In addition to the factors already mentioned, it is bad social etiquette. People view it as gaming the system for reputation points (repwhoring is the colloquial) and it still degrades the signal to noise ratio. Duplicates are tolerated as honest mistakes but they also dilute the changes visitors have of getting to the right place the first time and in an ideal world they would not exist. Intentionally making reality _less_ ideal and _more_ cluttered is just bad form. **Please don't.**

Answer (score 4):

If there is already a Question and it isn't getting a lot of views:

- change the wording so it is easier to understand, but don't change what the question says (hope that makes sense)
- add Tags if the question is missing some high profile ones
- Change the Title so that it attracts people without changing the idea of the question.
- add a bounty to the question

these are some things that you can do (within reason) to attract attention to the existing question.

Posting a deliberate Duplicate isn't a good idea, it clutters the site and doesn't look good.

a deliberate Duplicate will be closed and then deleted by the community if not a Moderator